# ANDROID | send email attachment only with email clients

Tags: android, android-intent

Please read the my question carefully before marking it duplicate. thanks :)

I want to send an email with attachment. I have used ***ACTION_SENDTO***

Code:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
 intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
 intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{
          Wrapper.INSTANCE.getSupportEmail()});
 intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, getResources().getString(resourceTitleId));
 intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file://" + filePath));

 try {
        ctx.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send mail..."));
 } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
        Toast.makeText(ctx, "There are no email clients installed.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }
```

It shows only email clients, see the picture below:

[image: test]

> but attachment is not working except GMAIL.

I have also tried to achieve it with ***ACTION_SEND***

CODE:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
 intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{
                    Wrapper.INSTANCE.getSupportEmail()});
 intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, getResources().getString(resourceTitleId));
 intent.setType("message/rfc822");
 intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file://" + filePath));
```

it shows all the supported apps, please see the picture below:

[image]

> but attachement is working file on all email clients.

I have read on many stack-overflow answers that

`intent.setType("message/rfc822");`

this will solve my problem. but it does not.

**I want only email clients to be shown that also supports attachment.**

Answer (score 0):

```
String recepientEmail = ""; // either set to destination email or leave empty

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:" + recepientEmail));
startActivity(intent);
```

The point is to use ACTION_SENDTO as action and mailto: as data. If you want to let the user specify the destination email, use just mailto:; if you specify email yourself, use mailto:name@domain.com

Suggested method filters all the application, that can send email(such as default email app or gmail)